# Aplicação RoR no windows CE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-ce

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma possibilidade de fazer uma aplicação Rails para Windows CE ?

Precisamos fazer uma aplicação para rodar em um coletor de dados que possui o **Win CE**. Este dispositivo não terá acesso a rede **(off-line/batch)**

Alguém já precisou fazer algo assim ?

Comment: Pela minha experiência o Ruby on Rails dá bastante dor-de-cabeça para rodar em windows, sem contar que o Rails é um framework para Web (Cria um servidor HTTP e trabalha todo o resto em cima disso). Me parece que seria muito mais sensato usar somente Ruby (Sem o Rails) ou alguma outra linguagem com menos problemas de compatibilidade com o Windows (Eu pessoalmente prefiro evitar linguagens da Microsoft, então usaria algo como NodeJS, mas as linguagens da microsoft podem te ganhar tempo).

Comment: Rails é um framework para aplicações web. Não faz sentido tentar usar Rails para fazer um aplicativo para o Windows CE tanto quanto não faria usar ASP.NET ou JSF. O que você poderia fazer é usar Rails no lado do servidor como backend do aplicativo que roda no dispositivo móvel.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.nsbasic.com/ce/

NSBasic-CE cria código nativo para WinCE/Mobile. Usa linguagem Basic semelhante ao VB.
Cria arquivo CAB para instalar no dispositivo. Executa o programa localmente.

Somente para WinCE 5.x ou WinMobile 5.x/6.x (o WinCE 6.x tem kernel modificado)

O site diz que este produto foi descontinuado pq eles estão se concentrando no NSbasic Studio (para IOS,Android, etc.. - Menos para WinCE) - Mas, se solicitar o NSBasic-CE eles vendem.

Att,

Elvis Sales
Manaus-AM